# Does Android Studio not working with bitbucket anymore? WORKING

Tags: android, android-studio, bitbucket

**UPDATE:** solution was update git

In Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14 I got auth errors when trying push/pull/clone bitbucket repository, but when I switched to Canary 6, it works perfectly.

[image]

[image]

I tried many tricks: reset password, clean cash, delete C:\Users\Admin..AndroidStudioPreview3.2 folder, nothing helps

Comment: have you tried update your git?

Comment: jubayer, you save my day. thanks!

Comment: @Anddever what version of git do you have right now? I have 2.17.0 but I still have the same error

Comment: @LouisTsai 2.17.0